# Expression - equality

Tags: linear-algebra

How is this equality edited? I don't understand the two last expressions. Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kue07.png)

Comment: the $b_0^2$ seems to disappear for no apparent reason. Hard to say why without context.

Comment: Please use [mathjax formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).